# D3 adding donut chart within a tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip

I'm trying to display a donut chart within a tooltip. I thought it'll be simply just adding the function name or creating the chart within .html() but that isn't the case sadly. Can anyone tell me where i'm going wrong?

Here's my code:

```
tooltip.select('.label').html(donutChart());


function donutChart(){

    var dataset = {
      hddrives: [20301672448, 9408258048, 2147483648, 21474836480, 35622912,32212254720],
    };

    var width = 460,
        height = 300,
        radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range(["#2DA7E2"]);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null);

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius - 100)
        .outerRadius(radius - 70);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var path = svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(pie(dataset.hddrives))
          .enter().append("path")
         .attr("class", "arc")
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
        .attr("d", arc);
    svg.append("text")
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("class", "inside")
          .text(function(d) { return 'Test'; });




    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `donutChart` appends the `<svg>` to the body, not inside the tooltip.

A solution can be writing this in your `.html()`:

```
.html("<h1>My Donut Chart</h1><br><svg class='myDonut'></svg>")
```

And then call your `donutChart` after that line, remembering to change your `var svg`:

```
var svg = d3.select(".myDonut")
```

Take care for not repeating the same variable names, even if they are inside a function (separate scope)... it can cause unnecessary confusion.